# Why is rsyslog not listed when I run service?

Tags: systemd, rsyslog, system-v, rsyslogd

I'm trying to learn about rsyslog. On one of my linux boxes, I think that `rsyslog` has been configured to run through systemd based on this output:

```
>systemctl status rsyslog
rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-01-10 11:28:07 PST; 3 months 19 days ago
 Main PID: 954 (rsyslogd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
           L954 /sbin/rsyslogd -n

>ps ax | grep syslog
  954 ?        Ssl    6:22 /sbin/rsyslogd -n
```

On the other linux box, though, systemv (systemctl is not present) seems unaware that `rsyslogd` is running:

```
[root@box ~]# service --status-all | grep -i syslog 2>&1
[root@box ~]# ps ax | grep -i syslog
 7866 ?        Sl     1:49 /sbin/rsyslogd -n -c5 -i /var/run/syslogd.pid
```

Why this disparity?

On the second box, is the fact that rsyslogd is running but not "found" by `service` evidence that it was spawned "manually" from the command-line and not configured through one of `service`'s init.d scripts? (Sorry if my terminology is primitive).

What I actually wanted to achieve was: on the second box, I wanted to restart rsyslog, and I expected to do so by running something like `service rsyslog restart`. But not finding rsyslog when I ran `service --status-all` led me down this detour.

Box 1 configuration:

```
>uname -a
Linux box1 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 5 14:01:17 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
Release:        20
Codename:       Heisenbug
```

Box 2 configuration:

```
Linux box2 2.6.37+ #2 Tue Apr 18 03:07:09 PDT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What are the Linux distributions and versions of box1 and box2?

Comment: @TopHat - Updated post with box 1 distro. On box 2, I tried all methods for finding distro that google led me to: 1) uname -r (output did not have distro info), 2) lsb_release -a (command not found), 3) cat /proc/version (output did not have distro info), 4) cat /etc/*-release (file not found), 5) cat /etc/issue (file not found), 6) dmesg (I could not find a distro name in the output). So I couldn't get distro information on box 2 I'm afraid.

Comment: Interesting. So I'd expect rsyslog to be a service and accessible with older systems via the `service` command and newer systems with the `systemctl` command. Box1 is doing what I'd expect. I'm not sure how to try and replicate with box2 since we don't know the distro and version. :( If box2 uses `rpm` you could see if you can find the package of rsyslog in use with `rpm -qa | grep rsyslog`. If it was built from source then it won't show up with that command and that could explain why it doesn't have a service script.

Comment: @TopHat box2 isn't being amenable to investigation: when I tried `rpm -qa | grep rsyslog`, I got `rpm` usage text, as though it doesn't recognize the argument. This may be of interest: that usage text says `BusyBox v1.18.4` - I wonder if that reveals the Linux distro?

Comment: I think `BusyBox` is likely just a package. Does this work better? `rpm -q rsyslog` It may return with nothing. If it does return you could try `rpm -q --info rsyslog` for more information. We could also try running rpm on a more obviously installed package to try and glean OS information. Such as: `rpm -q --info bash` The "Vendor" would be a good item to check if it returns output

Comment: @TopHat - I don't know why box2 is so obstinate (but I'm also a Linux newbie): `rpm -q rsyslog` returned with "rpm: can't open 'rsyslog': No such file or directory", and `rpm -q --info bash` returned with `rpm: invalid option -- '-'`. Based on the help text, I tweaked that command a bit to `rpm -q -i bash` but that just came back with "rpm: can't open 'bash': No such file or directory".

Comment: It must be on an older version of rpm with different syntax than I've learned. It'd still be nice to figure out what distro and version this was. Perhaps we can figure out the distro and version from the repositories. does this command work? `yum list repositories`. If not, try this command: `ls -lah /etc/yum.repos.d/`

Comment: Neither of those commands worked. This must be some super stripped-down barebones version of Linux(?). I'm trying to digest @Nick's answer as well; I'm not there yet.

Comment: Yeah, if there are no repositories, then it's possible this Linux machine was not built using a package manager, but rather by building up source code. This could be a Gentoo or LFS for example. One other thing I can think of to try and find a repository directory in /etc/ is to run this command: `find /etc/ -type d -name "*repo*"` and see if that comes back with anything relevant. @Nick is very likely right if this is the bare-bones system it's starting to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Not from the command line, but perhaps from another initialization script.  In the bad old days, a command like

```
 $ sudo bash -c "find / -xdev -type f -print0 -size -1M | xargs -0 grep rsyslog"
```

or, more likely

```
$ sudo bash
# find / -xdev -type f -print0 -size -1M | xargs -0 grep rsyslog
```

will go through all the files on the system looking for plain files that contain the desired string.  The -mount option on find keeps it out of /proc, and these days grep is smart enough that it will note when the file appears to be a binary file that contains the string.  -print0 and the -0 option to xargs work together and insure that files with odd characters, spaces, for example, which might otherwise confuse the parser, are properly dealt with.  And "-size -1M" insures that only files that are one megabyte or smaller are looked at - files that are larger than that are not likely what you are interested - rsyslog will most likely be started from a script.

There is one other possibility, of course, and that is that the program is started remotely. I can easily imagine someone starting rsyslog from an ssh script that is tied to a particular key, that does only that thing, it might not even let you get a shell, the point of this being that you run syslogd when the machine that is supposed to receive the syslogs is there to take them.

A command like pstree can show you what is what's child, and while it is easily possible to get out from under your parent so that you are inherited by init,